# How to handle multiply request in axios in a row?

Tags: javascript, axios

I my case i have a array of objects

```
let arr = [
  {
    data: "data1"
  },
  {
    data: "data2"
  },
  {
    data: "data3"
  }
];
```

i wanted to make a call in loop like this:

```
arr.forEach(() => {
    axios.post(url, el.data).then(res => {
      console.log(res.data);
    });
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

which in this case is looping through array and sending all request like machine gun and then they are coming back individually.

What i want is to make first call (first item in array) than wait for response when it comes back correct or error no matter just response. When i get it. I want to make second etc. as long as array has object init.

i found something like this but i do not understand if it will do

```
const axios = require('axios');
function makeRequestsFromArray(arr) {
    let index = 0;
    function request() {
        return axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/' + index).then(() => {
            index++;
            if (index >= arr.length) {
                return 'done'
            }
            return request();
        });

    }
    return request();
}

makeRequestsFromArray([0, 1, 2]);
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate

Comment: Yes, it will do. You might want to add a `.catch` ...

Comment: @JonasWilms i do not want to wait for them as send as a pack and then stored responses in array or state i need to make first call wait for response. After response is is back send second etc.

Comment: yes, i get that

Comment: ok thanks, so above code will serve this purpose?

Comment: Ok, the new duplicate question is better. But damian might not have access to `async/await` in his front end code. @Damian what is your build environment?

Comment: react so i will have access. but still i do not now how to handle this

Comment: https://pastebin.com/gyu0WzAZ

Comment: thanks @AvinKavish your code will not stack response but run each async loop once previous call get resolved/response came back?

Comment: ok works fine, but how can i prove to my collegue that it is doing as expected?. That next call is called after previous is resolved came back? sorry for silly questions.

Comment: you can open the developer tools in your browser and watch the requests in the network tab. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/